# Prevent variable update after page refresh without javascript

Tags: php, javascript

A friend of mine is developing a web application that's more of an online learning facility. On each page is a set of questions. He wants that when the use has answered all the questions on a page and submitted (and taken to the next page for the next set of questions), he shouldn't be able to go back to answer and resubmit those questions again. The idea is that "opportunity comes but once".

He doesn't want to use javascript because it can be disabled which leaves him with server-side coding. He uses PHP.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Thank you @Edgar. As noted in the question, I'll have to pass this suggestion to him to implement. It sounds plausible, though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)? This 'feature' can be really are handy when you want data persistance.

There is also the option of using hidden fields to pass the value but in my humble opinion sessions are cleaner.

Comment: I just about this. In case the user closes the browser, which is better at retaining the values, the session or cookie variable?

Comment: Session variables would probably be a better solution. It also uses a cookie, but it will definitely be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use some sort of database, the easiest way would be to set cookies for the user with PHP. You'd store which questions have already been answered and check that cookie server-side.